# neo4j debugger port won't attach

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, neo4j, cypher

Neo4j debugger port `5005` won't attach

neo4j version: `4.3.3`

java version:

[image]

[image]

I added
`dbms.jvm.additional=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005` to `neo4j.conf`.

[image]

[image]

Here is `neo4j.log`:

```
2021-09-25 13:13:57 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.
2021-09-25 09:43:59.029+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-09-25 09:44:01.984+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.3 ========
2021-09-25 09:44:04.397+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\neo4j-enterprise-4.3.3\metrics
2021-09-25 09:44:04.423+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2021-09-25 09:44:05.095+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-09-25 09:44:05.096+0000 INFO  Started.
2021-09-25 09:47:17.764+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2021-09-25 09:47:23.045+0000 INFO  Stopped.

2021-09-25 13:17:24 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.
2021-09-25 09:47:25.347+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-09-25 09:47:28.253+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.3 ========
2021-09-25 09:47:30.671+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\neo4j-enterprise-4.3.3\metrics
2021-09-25 09:47:30.694+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2021-09-25 09:47:31.355+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-09-25 09:47:31.356+0000 INFO  Started.
2021-09-25 09:48:24.434+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2021-09-25 09:48:29.686+0000 INFO  Stopped.

2021-09-25 13:18:30 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.
2021-09-25 09:48:31.794+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-09-25 09:48:34.706+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.3 ========
2021-09-25 09:48:37.075+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\neo4j-enterprise-4.3.3\metrics
2021-09-25 09:48:37.098+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2021-09-25 09:48:37.756+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-09-25 09:48:37.757+0000 INFO  Started.
2021-09-25 09:53:51.097+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2021-09-25 09:53:56.148+0000 INFO  Stopped.

2021-09-25 13:23:56 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.
2021-09-25 09:53:58.409+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-09-25 09:54:01.768+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.3 ========
2021-09-25 09:54:04.623+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\neo4j-enterprise-4.3.3\metrics
2021-09-25 09:54:04.645+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2021-09-25 09:54:05.399+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-09-25 09:54:05.400+0000 INFO  Started.
2021-09-25 09:56:36.540+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2021-09-25 09:56:41.812+0000 INFO  Stopped.

2021-09-25 13:26:42 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.
2021-09-25 09:56:44.002+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-09-25 09:56:47.046+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.3 ========
2021-09-25 09:56:49.652+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\neo4j-enterprise-4.3.3\metrics
2021-09-25 09:56:49.682+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2021-09-25 09:56:50.700+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-09-25 09:56:50.702+0000 INFO  Started.
2021-09-25 09:57:23.827+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2021-09-25 09:57:29.074+0000 INFO  Stopped.

2021-09-25 13:27:29 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.
2021-09-25 09:57:31.109+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-09-25 09:57:34.116+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.3 ========
2021-09-25 09:57:36.586+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\neo4j-enterprise-4.3.3\metrics
2021-09-25 09:57:36.606+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2021-09-25 09:57:37.334+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-09-25 09:57:37.336+0000 INFO  Started.
```

Comment: Settings didn't added properly.. If it is added  this line will be in the logs "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005"

Comment: dbms.jvm.additional=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005